# Calculate the circulation of the vector field alone a parameterized circle (Stoke's Theorem...?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem, curl

Find the circulation of the following vector field

$\vec{F}(x, y, z) = \langle \sin(x^2+z)-2yz, 2xz + \sin(y^2+z), \sin(x^2+y^2)\rangle$

along the circle $\vec{r}(t)=\langle\cos(t), \sin(t), 1\rangle$ with $t\in [0, 2\pi]$.

I tried using Stoke's theorem to solve it, but I get a difficult integral trying it this way:

$$\oint \vec{F}\cdot dr = \iint_S \nabla \times \vec{F} \cdot ds = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \vec{r}'(t) \,dt$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calculate $r^{\prime}(t)$ first. Should give you $(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)$, also isn't $F$ and $r$ vectors, please use appropriate notation next time.

Comment: Also, try applying Greens' theorem first rather than Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @Ajay Apologies, still getting used to LaTeX I must've forgotten. But doesn't Greens' theorem apply to vector fields in $\mathbb{R^2}$? How would I apply Greens' theorem here? Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Are you not working with $x,y,z$ i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @Ajay Pardon, I meant $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Sorry i'm still only a high school student but i'll try to help here :-)

Comment: @Ajay No worries, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Ajay FYI, some people (although maybe not this case) use "Stoke's Theorem" to refer to the whole triple of things taught in multivariable calculus, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem

Comment: Anyway, @MarlinRodriguez, notice that the normal vector to the surface is just $\hat k$, the unit vector in the positive $z$ direction. That simplifies the middle integral tremendously.

Comment: @AmejiB. I see. So then $\iint_S \nabla \times \vec{F} \cdot ds = \iint_S (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[2xz+sin(y^2+z)] - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\sin(x^2+z^2)-2yz]) ds$. But so then the integral would have $4z$, how should I go about it from there?

Comment: @MarlinRodriguez Well, you can see the answer now. As they state, since $z=1$ in the surface, you can simply set it in the integral.

Comment: @AmejiB. Right, $z$ never changes. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ajay A couple of things. You don't need to use vector notation . as long as you mention the components it's totally fine. In the undergrad level you will see many books and authors dropping the arrow to signify it's a vector.  Secondly Green's theorem is just a special case of stoke's theorem in a plane parallel to $xy-plane$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Noted, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: Thanks for letting me know :-). Very sorry if I have confused you Marlin, I shouldn't have said anything. Hope you can forgive me.

Comment: This is a friendly site @Ajay . You don't need to apologize for anything. We were merely engaging in a discussion. In the process of learning it is vital to communicate and sort out each other's doubts .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: Oh ok, I just felt real bad having said things that were not correct so I thought it would be appropriate to apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all notice that when you apply stokes theorem and try and calculate the surface integral, the $\vec{ds}=dxdy\,\hat{k}$ . So you only need the last component of the curl. i.e

$$\iint_{S}\nabla\times F\,.\vec{ds}=\iint_{S'}\left(\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}\right)dxdy$$ . Where $S'$ is the circular region in the plane $z=1$ such that $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$.

So you get :-

$$\iint_{S'}4z\,dxdy$$. (Substitute $z=1$ , as you are in this plane)

$$=4\iint_{S}dxdy=4(\text{Area of circle})=4\pi$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton!